# How to stop browser from creating gap near table when browser scrollbar appears

Tags: html, firefox, html-table

A small gap occurs to the right of a table when the following conditions are met:

- table border is greater than 1px
- border-collapse is collapse
- browser vertical scrollbar is visible
- browser is firefox

Here is some sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <style type="text/css">
        body {background-color:green;}

        table
        {
            background-color:#fff;
            width:600px;
            border-collapse:collapse;
            border:4px solid #222;
            /*border-spacing:0;*/
            margin: 0px auto;
        }

        tr {height:56px;} 

        td
        {
            font-family: trebuchet ms;
            font-size: 10.0pt;
            font-weight:bold;
            border:1px solid #222;
            padding-left:4px;
        }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <table>
        <tr >
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
        </tr>
        <tr >
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
            <td>some content</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any ideas are appreciated.

Comment: I just noticed that if I remove the doctype statement, the problem appears to be resolved; however, I am uncertain that I will be able to make that change without causing other problems.

Comment: do you use a reset.css to reset the browsers standard css?

Comment: No. I'm not sure how that would apply to this situation.